# Need help in solving complicated integral

Tags: integration, computer-algebra-systems

How this integral could be solved? Mathematica and Rubi failed.

$$\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }a \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left(z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2+z_4^2+z_5^2+z_6^2\right)}dx_6dx_5dx_4dx_3dx_2dx_1$$

with

$a =\sqrt{(z_1 z_5 - z_2 z_4)^2 + (z_3 z_4 - z_1 z_6)^2 + (z_2 z_6 - z_3 z_5)^2}$

$z1 = p1 + x1$

$z2 = p2 + x2$

$z3 = p3 + x3$

$z4 = p4 + x4$

$z5 = p5 + x5$

$z6 = p6 + x6$

where $p_1$,...,$p_6$ are free variables.

Comment: Have you realised that $a$ is the magnitude of $u\times v$ where $u$ is the vector in 3d space that gives the first three components of $z$ and $v$ is the last three, and $\times$ is the cross product?

Comment: You could try using $\left\Vert u\times v\right\Vert ^{2}=\left\Vert u\right\Vert ^{2}\left\Vert v\right\Vert ^{2}-\left(u\cdotp v\right)^{2}$